# Insert Data in Listview by Column in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview

Normally we are inserting data into Listview by Row. As example

```
No.  Item  Price   Status  Date
 1.   A     9.90    Pass   1/1/14
 2.   B     10.00   Pass   3/1/14
 3.   C     11.00   Failed 4/2/14
```

But i do want to add data by column. As example

```
No.  Desc   1/1/14   3/1/14   4/2/14
 1.  Item      A        B         C
 2.  Price    9.90    10.00    11.00
 3.  Status  Pass    Pass      Failed
```

I don't know how to start this logic. I hope anyone can help me. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
        ListView1.DataSource = myData.Tables["Customers"]; 'DataSet and DataTable name
        ListView1.DataTextField = "CustomerName"; 'Column you want to show
        ListView1.DataValueField = "CustomerId"; 'Value
        ListView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: im using ListView, not the listbox.

Comment: Just use the same method ( I updated mine), most of those controls have almost the same functions to be used.